# Disallow "guests can invite" option on creating a facebook event over open graph api

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

This may be a trivial thing which may be solved by using a different privacy option, but I have tried it all and either I'm stupid or it just isn't possible.

```
Facebook facebook = getFB();
MultiValueMap<String, Object> data = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
data.set("name", command.name);
data.set("start_time", command.start_date);
data.set("end_time", command.end_date);
data.set("privacy_type", command.privacy);

String fbEventId = facebook.publish("me", "events", data);
```

command.privacy is either 'SECRET' or 'OPEN'.
Now, when it's 'SECRET', I would like the option "guests can invite" to be disabled. I haven't found anything in the documents - help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.